# Ajax call does not work properly and refreshing table data with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, servlets

I am currently developing a web app. What i need, first of all, is when my html page loads, to invoke an ajax call to my servlet, which will search a database and return as response all the entries of a table as an html table. Whatever i have tried this does not seem to work, although i am using a ready function in which i do the ajax call.
Secondly when my html table is created, a verify button is added to unverified entries. What i need is when i press the verify button to call my servlet, update my database and then refresh my html table.

**adminPage (servlet)**

```
public class AdminPage extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String result = "";
    System.out.print("in get");
    try {
        // loading drivers for mysql
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        // creating connection with the database
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ted", "root", "Sk1994!!");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from user");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        int accepted = 0;

        result = "<table class='table table-striped'><thead><tr>";
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
            String name = rsmd.getColumnLabel(i);
            System.out.println("h sthlh legetai:  |" + name + "|");
            if (name.equals("accepted"))
                accepted = i;
            result += "<th>" + name + "</th>";

        }
        System.out.println("column is: " + accepted);
        result += "<th>Verification</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

        while (rs.next()) {
            boolean verified = true;
            result += "<tr>";
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
                result += "<td>" + rs.getString(i) + "</td>";
                if (accepted == i)
                    if (rs.getString(i).equals("0"))
                        verified = false;
            }
            if (verified)
                result += "<td></td></tr>";
            else
                result += "<td><button onclick='runPop(this);'>Validate</button></td></tr>";
        }
        result += "</tbody></table>";
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    out.println(result);

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    System.out.print("in post");
    String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
    System.out.println("Arxise");
    try {
        // loading drivers for mysql
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        // creating connection with the database
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ted", "root", "Sk1994!!");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("update user set accepted=? where username=?");

        String newValue ="1";       

        ps.setString(1, newValue);
        ps.setString(2, uname);
        ps.executeUpdate();     



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

I am using bootstrap and angular in my html page, i have removed most the included things 
**Js and ajax calls**

```js
function myFunction() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '../adminPage',
    success: function(data) {
      $("#result").html(data);
    }
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {

  myFunction();

});

function runPop(el) {
  var report = el.parentNode.parentNode.cells[1].innerHTML;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../adminPage',
    data: {
      "uname": report
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../adminPage',
        success: function(data) {
          $("#result").html(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <title>Tempting EveryDay</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
  <link href="../css/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom Fonts -->
  <link href="../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Theme CSS -->
  <link href="../css/agency.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../css/agency.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>




  <div id="result"></div>

  <button type="submit" onclick="myFunction();">press me</button>


  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
  <script src="../js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/contact_me.js"></script>

  <!-- Theme JavaScript -->
  <script src="../js/agency.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular js -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/app.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

The output i want is this:
[wanted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W21qj.jpg)

i ve managed to show it by adding a button to do the ajax call manually, but even then, when i press the validate button, ajax post is not done and servlet is not called. 
Also even if i update the database manually, when i refresh the page the html table does not update.

I am asking too much but every single clue could help me a lot. Thanks

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console? What do you see in the Response section of the Network tab?

Comment: Nothing. When i press the validate button the ajax-post is not called. I know because i don't get output from the servlet in the console. 
The whole validate thing has worked in another context and that's why i don't get why it does not work like this...

Comment: The code looks fine here, you must be doing something different on the actual site. Do you have a public link to it?

Comment: No, it's a personal project. Could the bootstrap or the agency be messing with the javascript ?

Comment: That's not likely. Does it work if you take them out?

Comment: Yeah i removed, some of them and validate worked, There might be an error in the other files, i ll check it later. 
But still, $( document ).ready(function() does not call the servlet, and when i validate, even if refresh the page and get my results by pressing the button (as seen in html) the html table is not updated (sql table is updated for sure, i check my database manually)

Comment: If you go into the Javascript debugger and put a breakpoint into `myFunction`, does it stop at the breakpoint?

Comment: As a debugger i am currently using firebug in firefox, so i don't think i can add a breakpoint on the  $( document ).ready(function() since page is already loaded when i see the code. I am developping in eclipse, but i don't think there is a javascript debugger there

Comment: I use Chrome, and if I set a breakpoint and then reload the page, the breakpoint is remembered. I don't use Firebug, so I don't know if it works the same way.

Comment: I checked that, firebug does the same thing. When page loads myFunction is not called, though the rest ajax calls are done correctly.

Comment: I can't think of any good reason why using bootstrap and angular would interfere. Many people use them together with jQuery.

Comment: If you are loading the javascript in your example at the end of the document body (i.e. after all of the html elements), there is no need to use the $( document ).ready(function().  Try removing it and calling myFunction() at the top of the js file.